# A DC - DC converter that needs a constant high on the enable pin?

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter

I'm trying to stabilize a battery output using a DC-DC converter. I got some Murata  ICs for testing ([LXDC2HL](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/281/2HN_E-366250.pdf) and [LXDC2HN](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/281/LXDC2HL_Series_datasheet_E-837146.pdf)). The datasheet gives an example of the circuit:

[image]

The EN pin confuses me. I need a DC-DC converter to get a stable power from the battery, but a prerequisite for it to work it needs an already stable 3.3V on the enabled pin. I'm failing to see the use case for this feature. Does this make the IC useless for a voltage regulation on an autonomous battery only powered circuit?

Comment: Read the datasheet again, you don't need "an already stable 3.3V"

Comment: In the pin table, it has this to say "Pulling this pin to Vin enables the device with soft start."

Comment: In many applications where you don't care about enabling it, you can just tie it to Vin (careful with maximum volatge ratings of the EN pin though, it might need a resistor divider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm failing to see the use case for this feature.

I use this feature on a similar DC-DC converter, because when the converter is *disabled*, its current drain is so low. On the converters you mentioned, the spec is max 2 uA leakage current when disabled.

> Does this make the IC useless for a voltage regulation on an autonomous battery only powered circuit?

For *some* battery-powered designs, imho the opposite is true - this feature is especially useful! :-)

That is because you can have a very low-power component (e.g. MCU mostly in sleep or stop mode) which is always powered from the battery, with suitable UVLO / brownout detector. That device then switches the EN pin of the DC-DC converter when required (e.g. depending on an MCU timer or a periodically-checked ADC reading etc.) which then supplies power to the relatively high-power components.

So when the high-power components can be powered-down, this is commanded via the MCU and the DC-DC converter then draws just that maximum of 2 uA. For some battery-powered applications (e.g. those with intermittent power usage requirements) that increases the overall battery life, rather than leaving the DC-DC converter running permanently. Having this functionality built-in to the converter removes the need for a separate P-Channel MOSFET switch external to the converter, to achieve a similar type of power-down function.

Summary: That is the "use case" where I have used a DC-DC converter "enable pin" feature. Of course those people who don't need that feature, can use the DC-DC converter with an enable pin in an "always-enabled" configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to connect Vin to EN. If you want the output to have a constant stable voltage, EN needs to be high. The equivalent circuit would be.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1e1im.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>